# Why NSNumber become zero from one function to another function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, nsnumber

I know this question is very basic but as a java programmer I am confused why this value is becoming zero? I have UITableView and I am trying to send the selected row number to destination UIViewController. However, this is before even sending this value it becomes zero in `prepareForSegue`

```
NSNumber* val;
/*segue*/
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

        //Perform a segue.
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toInfo"
                                  sender:[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        val = [[NSNumber alloc] init];

        val = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@"val111 === %@",val);  >>>Here prints 2
    }


    - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
    //    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toInfo" sender:sender];
        NSLog(@"inside segue");
        NSLog(@"val222 === %@",val);  >>> Here prints null




      InfoViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.journeyId = val;

     }
```

Comment: because you assign value to val after performSegueWithIdentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` (which in turn calls `prepareForSegue:sender:` *before* you've initialized `val`, so just as in Java, `val`'s going to be `nil` at that point. Just move your `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` call to the end of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`--or better yet, get rid of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and instead just create a segue from the table row to the destination view controller.

Moreover, you don't need the `val = [[NSNumber alloc] init];` line, because the following line creates and returns the `NSNumber` instance.

Comment: Thanks you so much. first I didn't have alloc and init. I just made a silly mistake.